# Changing the location where my domain resolved to on a Nginx server

Tags: django, nginx, linode

I have my DND set to my domain name and I want to load a installation of a Django website I have installed.

When I load [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) it loads a mydomain but from  **/var/www/html** but I want it to load from **/home/myname/kkappDashboard**;

I'm using a Nginx server and here is the sites-available configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 151.236.222.57 www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/myname/kkappDashboard;
        }
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myname/kkappDashboard/kkappDashboard.sock;
        }
    }
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    # redirect
    return 301 https://mywebsite.com.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

}
```

nginx.conf file

```
##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 151.236.222.xx;
    return 301 $https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location /static/ {
  root /kkappDashboard;
}
```

Above location block maps URIs `//static/*` to files `/kkappDashboard/static/*`.

---

If you wish to serve file `/kkappDashboard/file.txt` (without `static/`), consider trying:

**[`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)**

```
location ~ ^/static/(.*)$ {
  alias /kkappDashboard/$1;
}
```

**[`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)**

```
location ~ ^/static(/.*)$ {
  root /kkappDashboard;
  try_files $1 =404;
}
```